# Python: Necessary to catch open() exceptions?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm opening files in multiple functions, and it seems a bit messy/superfluous to keep 'gracefully' handling potential IOErrors:

```
try:  
    fileHandle = open(file, 'r')  
except:  
    print "Error: failed to open file %s" % (file)  
    sys.exit(2)
```

In what contexts is it acceptable to just:

```
fileHandle = open(file, 'r')
```

and expect the user to eyeball traceback messages in the case of exception?

Comment: You should really use "with" when working with files.
http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: It depends on who your program is for. Do you want your users to see error messages? Are you 95% sure that the program will work as expected? Will the few times it fails justify the work you put into it? It's up to you.

Comment: 'with' requirements: Python2.5 `from __future__ import with_statement`, or implicitly in Python2.6+.  (..and company I'm at uses Python2.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the principle of exceptions as implemented in Python and other languages. The exception handling in not necessary *local* to the function that raise the exception.

If some local processing is meaningful, do it. If you can't do anything useful, just let the exception go up in the call stack until a proper exception handler is found.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

---

If you *catch* an exception just in order to log it, you might want to re-raise it:

```
try:  
    fileHandle = open(file, 'r')  
except IOError:  
    print "Error: failed to open file %s" % (file, )  
    raise
```

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your application in an outer try/except that prints something a little nicer and logs the gory details. I didn't setup a logger here, but you get the drift:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import traceback

try:
    my_application(params)
except (OSError, IOError), e:
    message = "%s - %s." % (e.filename, e.sterror)
    sys.stderr.write("Error: %s. See log file for details%s" % (message, os.linesep))
    logger.error('myapp', message)
    for line in traceback.format_exc().split(os.linesep):
        logger.warn('myapp', line)
    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'with' keyword.

```
with open(file, 'r') as fileHandle:
    do_whatever()
```

This code is more-or-less equivalent to

```
try:
    fileHandle = open(file, 'r')
except IOError:
    pass
else: 
    do_whatever()
finally:
    fileHandle.close()
```

Basically, it makes sure that you open and close your files correctly, and catches exceptions.

Comment: wrt your second example, if `file` failed to open, wouldn't `fileHandle` be undefined thus causing issues in the `finally:` block?